# 64k limitation while testing - Android

Tags: android, gradle, dex

I'm trying to run some tests on a specific module in my android application but for some reason I keep getting these build error message:

```
Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
Error:Execution failed for task ':javadgd:transformClassesWithDexForDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.android.dx.command.Main with arguments {--dex --num-threads=4 --output C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\androidTest\debug\folders\1000\1f\main C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\classes_03333ab422775c158385448eafde7255a8524b93.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\javax.inject-1_721956a06ac86a777d8de583b4c13faebe0d5c5c.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\classes_94d5d0d0b278f09742c1e1dd1e53e80c88aeaba2.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\classes_2fd8a6413454d324a2bc2c41cedf751944c4a85a.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\jsr305-2.0.1_d0dc22afb31a509a829f5e56cd36e012ebe188e5.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\classes_feb1c246f0d10c407b60ae0ecd1d6ea8d8beca61.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\debug_f41558349a77243324d91f8782be0d487cd7d6ed.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\pkix-1.51.0.0_b76041394e3ad7737254c45a49f806aadb0e59da.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\hamcrest-core-1.3_92e7cef8754982c623a8492d3b3952651a36c08f.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\parceler-1.1.8_c0288db4cd1aae135e8b25494edc84eb400f3614.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\classes_6375c37ed5b22eb7cf9cd3a95bff1c6408d121ab.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\classes_bfa059c3d3a726ece320b7ef44fc899d58e51e52.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\classes_c7168d8cf335e64692d4939d085bc7489d9e37ee.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\classes_f1704eb11b8725da59212cbcea409be026a3ffcd.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\classes_67453a78ef3c9cab581c393c472c3c3d612dcc16.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\javax.annotation-api-1.2_99de26727b595d3c7e23682b1e351f77584621a6.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\classes_19aa33b9e42e4289994b07b2a0039e60888115cc.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\classes_b8055fc216a8eb86450b50466066c1960737277b.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\parceler-api-1.1.8_63d56b028e1b1695ca7293e1f2a92c9d9a0991f3.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\junit-4.12_70f50e338c3877b7b2e790ad100069bbc42c9c8f.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\classes_76cd03c23e8d9d3dc8f3c881ebccac6befa92db3.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\classes_f4edc33f0197e9449d5db5d862506bf37fe1c439.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\classes_25f2307ba0685e5e9569cd17ea92c99bb4649923.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\hamcrest-library-1.3_cc5997a988d1cb5dc61f56c2702d0209d499e271.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\prov-1.51.0.0_3793358556a1c80f36dba381de93ced0fc398087.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\classes_c06d6884053b63859253ba8751a5baef40098a74.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\support-annotations-25.1.0_8b16b00a90b3b73a336a7720f92a8e291227f223.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\core-1.51.0.0_f14b10294d4c741e145544e7806a68f73f58fe16.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\hamcrest-integration-1.3_77e530f0dc04d8547a01b2579bac749e0613dfdd.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\classes_4dc0d5d6487e5aaa62d200676a7d8d359cfdc7f6.jar C:\Projects\DGDEditor\javadgd\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\androidTest\debug\javawriter-2.1.1_cf45787cd93f38660e910b988d882dd18609ad89.jar}
```

I read about the 64k limit in android but I don't think it makes sense in my case. I don't have 64k method references in my app, nor do I have dependecies on libraries with 64k methods references(I think).

Here is my module-level build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"

            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
        compile 'com.tom_roush:pdfbox-android:1.8.9.1'
        compile 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.8'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.9'
    }
```

Project-level build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {

    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/shivasurya/materialsteppers" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I'm trying run instrumentation test inside the `androidTest` directory, due to a need for the `Context` of the target application.

Does anybody have a clue why do I get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is caused because when you runt tests you need to use other dependencies, such as `JUnit`, `Mockito`, etc. Those are used only when you run tests and methods count are added with your project mothods count.

In your gradle add this

```
default config {
  ....
  multiDexEnabled true
}
```

And if `minSdkVersion` < 20 you need to support

```
dependencies {
   ....
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Create an application class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
        ....
    }
}
```

And in your manifest you need to declare it

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication" >
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: I think the question was why the error exists, not how to enable Multidex

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The multiDexEnabled true did the trick. I didn't  have to create an `Application` class though.

Comment: If you test on a device with `minSdkVersion 19` i think will be the same error result. Is your choice.